# How to create a custom, hardcoded health check GraphQL query with AWS Appsync?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, aws-appsync-resolver

I'm new to AWS Appsync and to GraphQL.

Previously, I used to create REST APIs in Python. I was always creating a `GET` `/health-check` endpoint, sending back, for example and among many other info, the API version number, easily parsed from the project descriptor `pyproject.toml` file.
That helped me massively to maintain APIs: with a single `GET` query in my browser, I was always able to instantly get if branch/version it was, the status of other services, etc. .

I want to do something similar with AWS Appsync / GraphQL and my IaC tool (Pulumi).
Since I'm using IaC tool Pulumi in Python, I could still easily get the info I need and inject them in any resolver response template.

But if I create a resolver, should I create a corresponding health-check query itself in the GraphQL schema? When creating a resolver with a hardcoded JSON response, should it be associated with a GraphQL query in the schema, and if yes, how should that query in the schema look like?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way, but it's a very ugly workaround since AppSync VTL resolvers have a lot of limitations and since I'm using Pulumi as a Iac tool which also doesn't accept all arguments when creating a resolver - for example for `GetItem` operation it needs an `id` key in the request template.

I'm posting the workaround here anyway if it can be of any help to someone.

GraphQL schema:

```
schema {
  query: Query
}
type Query {
  getHealthCheck: String
}
```

AppSync `getHealthCheck` resolver request template:

```
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "operation": "GetItem",
    "key": {
        "id": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson(""),
    },
}
```

AppSync `getHealthCheck` resolver response template example:

```
"'version':'0.1', 'branch':'staging', 'commitId':'abc123'"
```

So in a IaC tool like Pulumi using Python, one could build the response template like that:

```
"""
"'version':'{}', 'branch':'{}', 'commitId':'{}'"
""".format(
    version,
    os.environ.get("GITHUB_REF_NAME", "unknown"),
    os.environ.get("GITHUB_SHA", "unknown"),
),
```